# General question about recursive formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, real-numbers

I have been trying to find an explicit formula for a sequence for a while now. I have found a recursive formula for it.

So my question is : is it possible for a sequence to have a recursive formula but no explicit formula? If so could you please provide an example?

Thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: Actually, it's only very special recurrences that can be solved explicitly, but it's hard to show that "no explicit formula exists."  What is the definition of an explicit formula?  It might be as well if you would post the specific recurrence you're working with.  Maybe someone will know something about it.

Comment: It's a sequence to do with the zeta function. I just wanted to ask since i have been working on it for a few months now and no good results so far.